# mysql on artix linux gives the 'ERROR 2002 (HY000)'

Tags: mysql, mariadb, runit, artix-linux

I'm using artix linux with runit init system and I've stumbled upon this issue where I can't login into mariadb by using

```
sudo mysql -u root -p
```

because it gives me the following error:

```
ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
```

Have anyone had a problem like this before?
I think it has something to do with runit not picking up the path to the mariadb.

Answer (score -1):

This can be due to mysql service not running.
Check whether mysql is active using this command:

```
systemctl status mysql
```

If it is not active/running, you need to use:

```
systemctl start mysql
```

Comment: Artix Linux does not use systemd.

Comment: The issue is likely mysql not running. I have experienced this issue. I don't know the equivalent command for Arch